# Trying to send signed transaction through web browser using ethereum-tx

Tags: web3js, transactions, ethereumjs-tx, sendrawtransaction

I am working on signing and sending a transaction using web3 v1.0 and Infura.io. I have setup a script to run the TX but cannot seem to get ethereum-tx to connect in the browser.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.34/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ethereum-tx.js"></script>
```

I dowloaded ethereum-tx.js from github and reference but keep getting the error TX is undefined.

```
var transaction = new TX(txData);
```

Does ethereum-tx not work in the browser? It works on the local machine after doing the npm install.

Here is the link to the download I am using -

```
https://github.com/ethereumjs/browser-builds/blob/master/dist/ethereumjs-tx/ethereumjs-tx-1.3.3.min.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two elements that could help solving your problem:

- You are calling `new TX(txData)` instead of the recommended way `new EthereumTx(txParams)`. Now, this might be to simple different naming of variables on your side, but sticking to the standards is often helpful in debugging.
- Besides, `ethereumjs-tx` depends on some JS ES6 capabilities, which are not always supported by the browsers. Hence you can use so-called *shims*, which patch the missing capabilities of the browser. For `ethereumjs-tx`in particular, there is a disclaimer that you should consider using [this shim](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim).

Hope this helps!